# XSLT how to remove empty elements and their parent nodes

Tags: xslt

I have this input XML:

```
<mods:relatedItem type="constituent">
    <mods:name type="corporate">
        <mods:namePart>Financijer projekta</mods:namePart>
    </mods:name>
    <mods:name type="corporate">
        <mods:namePart/>
    </mods:name>
    </mods:name>
        <mods:namePart/>
    </mods:name>
    </mods:name>
        <mods:namePart>Program financiranja</mods:namePart>
    </mods:name>
    <mods:identifier>Šifra projekta</mods:identifier>
    <mods:identifier/> 
    <mods:titleInfo>
        <mods:title>Naziv projekta</mods:title>
    </mods:titleInfo>
    <mods:titleInfo>
        <mods:title/>
    </mods:titleInfo>
    <mods:titleInfo type="alternative">
        <mods:title>Akronim projekta</mods:title>
    </mods:titleInfo>
    <mods:titleInfo type="alternative">
        <mods:title/>
    </mods:titleInfo>
</mods:relatedItem>
```

and I would like to get rid of all the elements that are empty, and their parent nodes.

the final XML should look like below:

```
<mods:relatedItem type="constituent">
    <mods:name type="corporate">
        <mods:namePart>Financijer projekta</mods:namePart>
        </mods:name>
        </mods:name>
        <mods:namePart>Program financiranja</mods:namePart>
    </mods:name>
    <mods:identifier>Šifra projekta</mods:identifier>
    <mods:titleInfo>
        <mods:title>Naziv projekta</mods:title>
    </mods:titleInfo>
    <mods:titleInfo type="alternative">
        <mods:title>Akronim projekta</mods:title>
    </mods:titleInfo>
</mods:relatedItem>
```

I tried making the transformation but never got the deleting  empty elements part to work

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/mods:mods/mods:relatedItem/mods:name[@type]/mods:namePart[not(string(.))]"/>
    <xsl:template match="/mods:mods/mods:relatedItem/mods:name[not(@type)]/mods:namePart[not(string(.))]"/>
    <xsl:template match="/mods:mods/mods:relatedItem/mods:identifier[not(string(.))]"/>
    <xsl:template match="/mods:mods/mods:relatedItem/mods:titleInfo[not(@type)]/mods:title[not(string(.))]"/>
    <xsl:template match="/mods:mods/mods:relatedItem/mods:titleInfo[@type]/mods:title[not(string(.))]"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you had well-formed XML, and the namespace URI was defined for the `mods` prefix, then it is usually best to start off with using the [Identity Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On its own, this copies all the nodes as-is, which means rather you only then need to write a template for the nodes you wish to delete. Ideally, you want to do this in a generic way, so this template should do

```
 <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text()[normalize-space()])]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text()[normalize-space()])]" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Btw, isn't `descendant::text()[normalize-space()]` semantically equivalent to `.[normalize-space()]`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The template match can be simplified to `<xsl:template match="*[not(.[normalize-space()])]" />`. And "its" is correct by the way ;)